# Acceder a variables de un request en Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Cuando hago un `dd($request)`, este me muestra un array con muchas variables, como `json`, `headers`, `cookies`, etc, mi pregunta es... puedo acceder a esas variables del `$request`, de alguna forma?

Comment: coloca por favor una muestra de la data que recibes

Comment: 1. Muéstranos lo que recibes, 2. Explícanos puntualmente a qué quieres acceder. Ya llevas un tiempo en el sitio, deberías saber cómo formular preguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder a la variable Referer del Request, debes usar el método server, usa la siguiente sintaxis:

```
Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')
```

Información más detallada en: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_server

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso era lo que queria saber.